# Data printing to Browser rather than file in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file, csv, printing, download

I've created a custom page template for my wordpress site that reads data from custom tables, manipulates it, and then puts into a form. This displays just fine.

the next thing the code does is call a function which is supposed to then take all the same data that's in the table, and put it into a CSV file which the user can open or download.

However, what's happening is that instead of the file being available for download, it's simply dumped into the page below the form.

Here's the code for the function that's supposed to print the file. It's a function that takes two arrays (header and main content), and the delimiter. Before this code comes the call to open the file. (php://memory, w)

```
    // Add report title
    fputcsv($f, (array)$headers_array[0], $delimiter);

    //add the date
    fputcsv($f, (array) $headers_array[1], $delimiter);

    //add notes
    fputcsv($f, (array) $headers_array[2], $delimiter);

    //labels from the document
    $headers_temp = explode (",",$headers_array[3]);
    //var_dump ($headers_temp);
    fputcsv ($f, $headers_temp, $delimiter);

    //headers that actually label the columns
    $headers_temp = explode (",",$headers_array[4]);
    //var_dump ($headers_temp);
    fputcsv ($f, $headers_temp, $delimiter);

    foreach ($array as $line) 
    { 
        // generate csv lines from the inner arrays
        //var_dump ($line);
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter); 
    }
    // reset the file pointer to the start of the file
    fseek($f, 0);
    // tell the browser it's going to be a csv file
    header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=utf-8');
    // tell the browser we want to save it instead of displaying it
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= report_for_"'.$headers_array[1] .'".csv;');
    // make php send the generated csv lines to the browser
    fpassthru($f);
```

This code functions *perfectly* when I'm not in a wordpress environment (I'm adapting mycode from pure PHP/HTML to incorporate it into a website) but doesn't work in Wordpress. Is there an object or wordpress function I should use instead of fopen?

Thanks

Comment: there is a site for WordPress developement questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: How do I put that question there? It won't let me post it? Can I crosspost it directly?